# Regex for numbers matches string with non-digit characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

My regular expression pattern is `@"\d+"`. However it always returns true for the string "9r651". I just want it to return true for string containing digits only (0-9). 
I just can't figure this out. Any help would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please choose a more descriptive title. "Regular expression" says nothing about your particular issue, and future readers trying to find solutions to a problem similar to yours won't be able to find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That pattern returns a positive match if the string contains one or more digits, in any position of the string.

What you want is a pattern that positively matches if the string contains nothing but digits.

`^\d+$`

Adding `^` at the beginning and `$` at the end means "the line must begin here, be followed by one or more digits, and then end"

Answer (score 6):

You need to [anchor your regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5181w5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), otherwise it will find matches anywhere inside the subject. Use `^\d+$` pattern.

`^` tells the regex engine that match should happen at beginning of the subject.

`$` tells the regex engine that match should happen at end of the subject.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
@"^\d+$"
```

^ says "line must start here" and $ says "line must end here"